# How do I change the plot axis (yaxis) without sorting the values from bottom to top

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written down a code to plot a hit map from a data set containing `40` rows and `5` columns. The data is plotted from bottom to top.

How can I change it so that my data plotting starts from top to bottom?

I used  `plt.invert_yaxis()` but its showing an error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'invert_yaxis'

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/home/jai/Desktop/jax.csv")
print df

plt.pcolor(df)

plt.invert_yaxis()

plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.index), 1), df.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.show()
```

Along side its not showing outline for each and every cell (values) how can I add this too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`invert_yaxis` is a method of an `Axes` object. If you use the `matplotlib` object oriented approach, you can call `invert_yaxis` on the axes

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.pcolor(df)

ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Alternatively, you can get the current axis using `plt.gca()`, and then call `invert_yaxis()`

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

---

As for your second question:

Try setting the edgecolors kwarg. e.g:

```
pcolor(df,edgecolors='k')
```

should set black outlines around each cell